# Can not save/delete localStorage token with page redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working on a project with angular & nodejs, there is a singin and logout function in my controller,

```
Main.signin(formData, function(res) {
  if (res.type == false) {
    alert(res.message);
  } else {
    $localStorage.token = res.token;
    $location.path('/'); // redirect to index page.
  }
}, function() {
  //failed processing.
});


$scope.logout = function() {
  Main.logout(function() {
    window.location = "/"
    window.location.replace("/");
  }), function() {
    alert("Failed to logout!");
  };
};
```

the logic of the above code is simple but I can't save or delete the token with `window.location = "/"`, but if I comment the `window.location = "/"`, after I execute above methods, then refresh the browser, the token is deleted or saved.

Does anyone have idea about this?

Comment: Why aren't you using `localStorage.setItem('token', res.token)`?

Comment: @Oleg I tried to use your suggested code but no lucky. :(

Comment: Which localStorage module are you using? Have you tried $localStorage.$reset() ?

Comment: @Yousef I am using ngStorage module and $localStorage.$reset() does not work neither.

Comment: @Oleg and Yousef, thank you guys, I replace $localStorage with $window.sessionStorage, everything goes well now.

Comment: @Yousef, looks it caused ngStorage's existed issue: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/issues/39

Comment: glad to see you figured it out!